# using replace_na() with indeterminate number of columns

Tags: r, dplyr, tidyr, tidyeval

My data frame looks like this:

```
df <- tibble(x = c(1, 2, NA),
             y = c(1, NA, 3),
             z = c(NA, 2, 3))
```

I want to replace NA with 0 using tidyr::replace_na(). As this function's documentation makes clear, it's straightforward to do this once you know which columns you want to perform the operation on.

```
df <- df %>% replace_na(list(x = 0, y = 0, z = 0))
```

But what if you have an indeterminate number of columns? (I say 'indeterminate' because I'm trying to create a function that does this on the fly using dplyr tools.) If I'm not mistaken, the base R equivalent to what I'm trying to achieve using the aforementioned tools is:

```
df[, 1:ncol(df)][is.na(df[, 1:ncol(df)])] <- 0
```

But I always struggle to get my head around this code. Thanks in advance for your help.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

We can do this by creating a `list` of 0's based on the number of columns of dataset and set the names with the column names

```
library(tidyverse)
df %>% 
   replace_na(set_names(as.list(rep(0, length(.))), names(.)))
# A tibble: 3 x 3
#      x     y     z
#   <dbl> <dbl> <dbl>
#1     1     1     0
#2     2     0     2
#3     0     3     3
```

Or another option is `mutate_all` (for selected columns -`mutate_at` or base don conditions `mutate_if`) and apply`replace_all`

```
df %>%
    mutate_all(replace_na, replace = 0)
```

---

With `base R`, it is more straightforward

```
df[is.na(df)] <- 0
```

Comment: Wowsers. Thanks!